# Using \adjustwidth seems to break with a figure caption in knitr

Tags: knitr

I need to adjust my margins so I can place two pictures side by side.  This works when there is no caption on the picture but when I add a caption the margins revert back to how they were.

```
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.75in}{-0.75in}
    <<tuning,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,fig.height=2,fig.width=8,fig.pos='H''>>=
    multiplot(inter_tree,inter_tree,cols=2)
    @
    \end{adjustwidth}


    \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.75in}{-0.75in}
    <<tuning,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,fig.height=2,fig.width=8,fig.pos='H',fig.cap='caption'>>=
    multiplot(inter_tree,inter_tree,cols=2)
    @
    \end{adjustwidth}
```

Here is what it looks like both with and without the caption:[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.